# Is p-dimensional matching with (p−1)n edges NP-hard? What about 3n edges?

Tags: np-hardness, matching

Let $p≥3$ an integer. I am wondering whether or not the following problems are NP-hard or not (and if they are, I am looking for a convincing argument, or even better a detailed proof):

1. Let $V_1,\dots,V_p$ disjoint vertex sets each of size $n$. There are $m=(p−1)n$ edges $E\subset V_1\times\dots\times V_p$. Determine whether or not there exists a matching of size at least $n$ or not.
2. Let $V_1,\dots,V_p$ disjoint vertex sets each of size $n$. There are $m=3n$ edges $E\subset V_1\times\dots\times V_p$. Determine whether or not there exists a matching of size at least $n$ or not.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This won't make a difference, because those few edges might be essentially concentrated on a small part of the $V_i$'s. Imagine that there are $n-\sqrt n$ vertices in each $V_i$ covered by only one edge, with a unique matching on them, while the rest of the $p\sqrt n$ vertices have a complicated graph on them.

Comment: This question was asked and answered on the math stackexchange, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212038/is-p-dimensional-matching-with-p-1n-edges-np-hard-what-about-3n-edges